# Get username / id for Facebook (messenger)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

On my website, I want to connect users through facebook messenger. I wanted to be able to store a user's id or username so that I can generate a http://m.me/`id or username`for that specific person.

I know it is no longer possible to get usernames or ids from the facebook api, but is there any other way to create a link for a specific profile? If I want get a link for a facebook profile its possible to use app_scoped_user_id like this 
https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/`id_from_sdk`. Is there a similar solution for messenger.com?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can still get the user's ID if you are using Codeigniter

```
$userInfos = $this->facebook->getUserInfos();
$user_facebook_id = $userInfos['id'];
```

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Codeigniter. Is [this](https://github.com/darkwhispering/facebook-sdk-codeigniter) the correct github repo?

Comment: Uhm, yea. are you using it on pure PHP? without framework?

Comment: I looked at some sample code where they call $this->facebook->request()

Comment: they then call  $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id']. is this different?